# Get access token and secret using OpenID+OAuth (google)

Tags: php, oauth, openid, lightopenid

I'm using [OAuth with Federated Login (Hybrid Protocol)](http://code.google.com/intl/vi-VN/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#oauth) to allow my users to login once using openID (which works great), and authenticate with the Google Data API at the same time.

The Zend_GData library was giving me a headache, so on the suggestion of someone here on SO I switched to [LightOpenID](https://web.archive.org/web/20141223022707/https://gitorious.org/lightopenid).

The openID part works great, and thanks to [this](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/issues/detail?id=35#c0) tip I'm able to add the OAuth extension and receive a response like this:

```
 http://www.example.com/checkauth
 ?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
 &openid.mode=id_res
 &openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
 &openid.response_nonce=2009-01-17T00:11:20ZlJAgbeXUfSSSEA
 &openid.return_to=http://www.example.com/checkauth
 &openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUeYs1o3pBTDPsLFdA9AcGKlH
 &openid.signed=op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle,ns.ext2,ext2.consumer,ext2.scope,ext2.request_token
 &openid.sig=oPvRr++f6%2ul/2ah2nOTg=
 &openid.identity=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id/id=AItOawl27F2M92ry4jTdjiVx06tuFNA
 &openid.claimed_id=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id/id=AItOawl27F2M92ry4jTdjiVx06tuFNA
 &openid.ns.oauth=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
 &openid.oauth.scope=http://docs.google.com/feeds/+http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/+http://sandbox.gmodules.com/api/
 &openid.oauth.request_token=1/fVr0jVubFA83GjYUA
```

According to the documentation, `openid.oauth.request_token` is an authorized request token, so it seems I don't need to do the `OAuthAuthorizeToken` request. All is good so far, but now I need to exchange this request token for an access token and token secret.

Since I have no idea how to generate the OAuth nonce and signatures, I employ the [OAuthSimple](https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/) library for php. Problem is, the code required looks like this:

```
// Build the request-URL...
$result = $oauth->sign(array(
    'path' => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken',
    'parameters' => array(
        'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier'],
        'oauth_token' => $_GET['oauth_token']),
    'signatures' => $signatures));
```

It needs an `oauth_verifier` value, which you would receive along with the request token with a normal OAuth request. I'm not sure if it's the OAuthSimple library that errors out when trying to omit that or if it's a Google requirement, but it doesn't work.

SO, can someone spot something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong. Actually, when you do an Hybrid process, the verifier isn't send, simply because you don't need it.

So in your code, just set verifier to NULL, and it should work just fine, as long as there's no problems somewhere else.